# Autocomplete a string if it ends with a specific substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field called domain. Users type in this field, I get the value, and in most cases I automatically attach ".com" to the end.

User types in "example" and an output shown elsewhere is "example.com".

I have a section of the script that prevents "example." from becoming "example..com".

```
// Convert to lower case, remove all non-valid characters, remove duplicate hyphens and periods, remove hyphens and periods from ends
var domain = document.getElementById('domain').value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9-\.]/g, '').replace(/(-+(?=-))|(\.+(?=\.))/g,'').replace(/(^-+)|(-+$)|(^\.+)|(\.+$)/g, '');
// Add the TLD that best matches if it needs one
if(!/\.(com|net|org)$/.test(domain) && domain != '') domain += '.com';
```

What I'm trying to do is append ".com" if the string ends in any part of ".com", append ".net" if the string ends in any part of ".net", and append ".org" if the string ends in any part of ".org".

If the user types in "example.c" it should become "example.com" and not "example.c.com".

If the user types in "example.net" it should stay as "example.net".

If the user types in "example.nett" it should become "example.nett.com".

I can test for nine different permutations (c, co, com, n, ne, net, o, or, org) but I'm trying to figure out a better way of doing this, especially if I want to support more TLDs down the road.

Comment: Why is the logic such that "If the user types in "example.nett" it should become "example.nett.com"."? Why not "example.nett" replaced with "example.net" or "example.nett.net"?

Comment: I don't want to account for typos. If someone types in something other than the start of .com, .net, or .org I'll assume the first part was a subdomain and I want to apply the same .com logic on the domain. If someone types in just nett I'd complete it to nett.com.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by splitting the string by the dot.

then if there is a value in the second index then you can throw that into a switch statement.

It would look something like this.

```
function append(domain){
    var parts = domain.split(".");

    if(parts.length == 1) // means there is no dot in the string
      return domain + ".com";

    switch(parts[1]){
      // your cases
    }
}
```